# Nginx - Nested if with query parameters

Tags: nginx

This is what I need to do:

- Check whether the request is from facebook
- Redirect the url using a parameter I receive as the query parameter
- If the url is not from facebook then return the normal page

I am using the following configuration:

```
location / {
            if ($args ~* "^param-1=(.*)&param-2=(.*)") {
                    set $paramVar "1";
                    set $args2 $2;
            }
            if ($http_user_agent ~* (facebookexternalhit)) {
                    set $paramVar "${paramVar}1";
            }
            if ($paramVar = "11") {
                    rewrite ^.*$ https://www.example.com/$args2? last;
            }
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/xyz;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

This works fine when calling from facebook sharing debugger but the normal call returns 404. I think it is because a normal call satisfies the first call but fails the second one.

I know that 'IFISEVIL', but is there some way to avoid using it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

First, your example is not a "Nested If". If so, that would look like

```
if ($cond1) {
   if ($cond2) {
     ...
   }
 ...
}
```

and that would be illegal in Nginx...

However, you can avoid *extra* "ifs" in your config by using Maps.

Map logic basically says (pseudo-code):

```
if $condtion1 = <param1> then set $var1 = <value1>
else if $condition1 = <param2> then set $var1 = <value2>
... <paramN> ... <valueN>
else set $var1 = <defaultValue>
```

Using a couple maps which provide Global Vars from the Http Context in the Nginx config, you can do things such as:

```
# if ($args ~* "^param-1=(.*)&param-2=(.*)") {
#      set $paramVar "1";
#      set $args2 $2;
# }
### Your logic reduces to: if query params begin with param-1=someVal
### then set $args2 = $2

### here is the equivalent map: 
map $args $param_1 {
    default "";
    ^~param-1&param-2 $args2;
}

### now let's detect that fb external hit
map $http_user_agent $fb_route {
    
    ~*facebookexternalhit 1;
    default 0;
}

### set $do_rw = 1 to implement our IF later using clean code
### note that Nginx is doing a literal concat of the 2 mapped vars
### thus "11" below means $param_1 = 1 AND $fb_route = 1
map $param_1$fb_route $do_rw {
    
    11 1;
    default 0;
}
```

And the resulting, single "If" directive is be placed in the Server or Location context:

```
### note that because $args2 and $do_rw are Global
### the following works:
if ($do_rw) {
  rewrite ^.*$ https://www.example.com/$args2? last; 
}
```

There are a couple call-outs I could make as to final production code and best-practices, but I have tried to replicate your code exactly as it is implied to work only reducing it as far as the immediate Maps implementation is concerned vs. "if's"

Note that Maps do have a performance impact, but less so than "if's" and Maps are cleaner than "if's". Using Maps you can also take advantage of  these Global Vars being set once and potentially consumed by several Virtual Hosts if you use SNI...

Finally- somewhat beyond the scope of the OP- I could use the Ngx_lua module to eliminate If's completely in this config...